# Modify the submitted manuscript to journal

Tags: publications, journals

I submitted my manuscript to journal. one week after submission I found out that 2 references must be added and a little modification is needed. we sent them an email,but any answer have not been received yet(Maybe due to chrismass holiday). My manuscript status is assigned reviewers. please answer following questions: 1. is it possible that the editor didn't answer because the manuscript sent to reviewers and the editor decided not to let me modify it before the reviewers announce the review result? 2.If the editor removed the manuscript in the profile,whenever I resubmit the modified version,Is it necessary to change the title and abstract?someone told me if i resubmit the modified version with the same title and abstract,they will reject it. 3. is this mistake which leads to email sending to editor and resubmit the manuscript, decrease my chance for acceptance? I have too much stress . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think the best course is just to wait for the reviewer reports. Probably they will suggest some changes. Make additional changes at that time and submit them with the revised manuscript. Otherwise it will just be confusing, even chaotic, for the editor and reviewers. Let the process run for a bit.

I'm assuming that the changes you want to make wouldn't make the difference between acceptance (with revision) and rejection. If you get rejected, revise and submit elsewhere.

But don't do things likely to confuse the editor.

Comment: Just to round up the answer: don't forget to list all changes you will made, even those not requested by the referees.